# Getting inconsistent facebook posts in response of Graph API call with me/home/

Tags: php, facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-3.0

Graph API call **https://graph.facebook.com/me/home** returns limited number of posts. Moreover response is having inconsistency in number of posts returned in response. Few of the posts are missing in response which i can see on my Facebook news-feed.

Inconsistency between results returned in Graph API test Console and My Application even though having same permission sets for both.

I need to know following.

1. The maximum number of posts I can retrieve from Facebook news-feed using graph api calls. (This information is not available anywhere in Facebook developer docs )
2. Is there any limitation for number of feeds that can be retrieved using api (i.e. feeds from last 2 weeks only or only 600 feeds not more then that)?
3. Why posts are getting filtered from response?

Demo Code URL : http://www.trimantra.com/demo/fbsocialfeeds/

Please do review attached demo code also. Demo code package is here http://www.trimantra.com/demo/fbsocialfeeds/fbsocilafeedsbug.zip

**Steps to Reproduce**

I'm working with latest Facebook PHP SDK and Graph API

1. Log in with Facebook and get basic permissions(export_stream, read_stream, user_friends)
2. Get an extended access token.
3. Create a loop from 1 to 30 and make a graph API call to me/home with limit=100 ([https://graph.facebook.com/[userid]/home?limit=100](https://graph.facebook.com/%5buserid%5d/home?limit=100))
4. Store response in a temporary array to calculate final result set.
5. Loop ends after 6 or 7 calls which returns nearly 600 to 700 individual Facebook posts in response.

**Expected Behavior**

1. In response I should get maximum number of posts from my news feeds. Exactly the same posts, in same order that i can see on my own Facebook news feeds.
2. I should be able to get feeds posted on yesterday and day before that and which are on my Facebook news-feeds.
3. Feeds should not get filtered in response.

**Actual Behavior**

1. I'm able to retrive not morethen 780 posts. Number of posts in response is random. Sometimes graph API returns 600 posts and sometimes 675 posts. On average I'm able to get nearly 670 post.
2. Some of the feeds are missing in response which I can see on my facebook newsfeed and Graph API test console. Which means my code and application is not giving the same results like Graph API Test Console.
3. order of posts is inconsistent in response and different from Facebook.

I would appreciate any reply or help.